# islower function to output boolean value of 0 or 1 depending on input

Tags: c++

I tried the following but am not getting 0 or 1. The question is how do I make this program print out a boolean value of 0 or 1 without using conditional statement in C++.

```
char input;
char output;
cout << "Input A Character: \n";
cin >> input;
input = islower(input);
cout << input;
```

Comment: Why can't you use a conditional statement? Is this homework?

Comment: If you want to print a boolean value why not use a boolean value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`islower` should return 0 when the character is NOT a lowercase letter.

Remember that only 0 is `false`. Even if the function returns -1, it's still a `true` value.

Check out the reference [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/islower/).

EDIT:

You can try using `input = 1 && islower(input);`. This will force you `true` value to become 1.

Comment: My bad.  I got the short circuting on `&&` and `||` backwards in my head.  I also checked around, I didn't think logical expressions (cast to int) would result in 0/1, but I was mistaken.  Your code is reliable.  Edited so I can remove the -1.

Comment: No worries, mate. It happens :). I've deleted my comments.

Comment: Actually, it's still a "bug".  The short circuit "&&" returns a boolean ... so "true" *STILL*won't necessarily be "0x01".  You need to use the bitwise "&": `input = islower(input) & 1;`

Comment: And if islower(input) is ... say ... 2? 2=010 , 1=001 => 2 & 1 = 0 in binary

Comment: Also, if it's just because of the short-circuit, you can just do `1 && islower(input)`. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 5):

To get either `0` or `1`, you can use the double `!` operation:

```
cout << !!input;
```

`!!` is a common idiom to normalize boolean values. It yields `0` when the value is `0` and `1` when the value is non-`0`.

Some people don't like the double negation, and you can get the same result with the `!=` equality operator:

```
cout << (input != 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `int` instead of a `char`:

```
int result = islower(input);
cout << result;
```

Note that islower is only guaranteed to return "0" or "something that isn't 0". You can fix that by writing `cout << (result ? 1 : 0)`, but I'm not sure if that is disallowed by your requirements.

Comment: The char type is autocast to int, so I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: autocast?? this is a correct answer, though he doesn't tell the whole picture.

Comment: Actually, cout will render a char as a "char".  Meaning "0" will be could be an unprintable binary code.  For example, this is how it looks with MSVC: Input A Character:
a
input: a, bIsLower: ☻

Answer (score 1):

Both 0 and 1 are non-printable characters, that's why you don't see the output. If you redirect the output to a file and open with a hex editor you'll see the result.

Store the result in a boolean, or cast the result: `cout << (bool) input;`

Comment: Or just output a value that is printable: `cout << ('0' + input)`

Comment: I'd prefer `std::cout << (int)input;`.  Slower, but safer

Comment: Wow! thanks Karoly your answer was helpful i tried the > cout << (bool) input; and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Every value except 0 == true. 0 == false.

Comment: Davita - I don't know what brain damaged troll marked you down - but you're absolutely correct :)

Answer (score 0):

you can store the output of `islower(input)` in an integer variable, say `value`, and `cout << value`

```
int value = islower(input);
cout << input;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int 
main() 
{
  char input;
  cout << "Input A Character: \n";
  cin >> input;
  unsigned int bIsLower = islower(input);
  cout << "input: " << input << ", bIsLower: " << bIsLower << endl;    
  return 0;
}
```

> Input A Character:
>   a
>   input: a, bIsLower: 2
>
> Input A Character:
>   A
>   input: A, bIsLower: 0
>
> Input A Character:
>   z
>   input: z, bIsLower: 2

Answer (score 0):

To print a boolean value use a variable of type **bool**.

```
   char input;
   bool output;
// ^^^^
   cout << "Input A Character: \n";
   cin >> input;
   output = islower(input);
// ^^^^^^  Store result in a bool variable (otherwise why have output)
   cout << output;   
//         ^^^^^^^  Now print it.
```